# Content remains under the sticky header

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

Can someone tell me why top of the `#page` where it reads `START` remains under header when scrolling back up?

Thanks in advance

**CSS**:

```
*
{
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}
#header, #page, #footer
{
    float: left;
    display: block;
    width: 100%;
}
#header
{
    background: #CCCCCC;
}
#default
{
    display: block;
    height: 100px;
    background: #64D989;
}
#sticky
{
    display: none;
    height: 50px;
    background: #D9D164;
}
#footer
{
    background: #EEEEEE;
}
```

**JS**:

```
$(document).ready(function ()
{
    $(window).bind("scroll", function (e)
    {
        if ($(document).scrollTop() >= 100)
        { 
            $("#header").css('position', 'fixed');
            $("#default").css('display', 'none');
            $("#sticky").css('display', 'block');
        }
        else
        {
            $("#header").css('position', 'fixed');
            $("#sticky").css('display', 'none');
            $("#default").css('display', 'block');
        }
    });
});
```

**HTML**:

```
<div id="header">
    <div id="default">I AM DEFAULT HEADER</div>
    <div id="sticky">I APPEAR IF SCROLL POSITION > 100px</div>
</div>

<div id="page">
        START<br /><br />
        CONTENT<br /><br /><br />
        CONTENT<br /><br /><br />
        CONTENT<br /><br /><br />
        CONTENT<br /><br /><br />
        CONTENT<br /><br /><br />
        CONTENT<br /><br /><br />
        CONTENT<br /><br /><br />
        CONTENT<br /><br /><br />
        CONTENT<br /><br /><br />
        CONTENT<br /><br /><br />
        CONTENT<br /><br /><br />
        CONTENT<br /><br /><br />
        CONTENT<br /><br /><br />
        CONTENT<br /><br /><br />
        CONTENT<br /><br /><br />
        CONTENT<br /><br /><br />
        CONTENT<br /><br /><br />
        CONTENT<br /><br /><br />
        END
</div>

<div id="footer">I AM PAGE FOOTER</div>
```

[jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/cfsep/)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Because you have to set back the initial position of #header when you scroll to top:0

```
$(document).ready(function ()
{
    $(window).bind("scroll", function (e)
    {
        if ($(document).scrollTop() >= 100)
        { 
            $("#header").css('position', 'fixed');
            $("#default").css('display', 'none');
            $("#sticky").css('display', 'block');
        }
        else
        {
            $("#sticky").css('display', 'none');
            $("#default").css('display', 'block');
            $("#header").css('position', 'fixed');
        }
        if($(document).scrollTop() == 0){
            $("#header").css('position', 'static');
        }
    });
});

<div id="header">
    <div id="default">I AM DEFAULT HEADER</div>
    <div id="sticky">I APPEAR IF SCROLL POSITION > 100px</div>
</div>

<div id="page">
        START<br /><br />
        CONTENT<br /><br /><br />
        CONTENT<br /><br /><br />
        CONTENT<br /><br /><br />
        CONTENT<br /><br /><br />
        CONTENT<br /><br /><br />
        CONTENT<br /><br /><br />
        CONTENT<br /><br /><br />
        CONTENT<br /><br /><br />
        CONTENT<br /><br /><br />
        CONTENT<br /><br /><br />
        CONTENT<br /><br /><br />
        CONTENT<br /><br /><br />
        CONTENT<br /><br /><br />
        CONTENT<br /><br /><br />
        CONTENT<br /><br /><br />
        CONTENT<br /><br /><br />
        CONTENT<br /><br /><br />
        CONTENT<br /><br /><br />
        END
</div>

<div id="footer">I AM PAGE FOOTER</div>

{
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}
#header, #page, #footer
{
    float: left;
    display: block;
    width: 100%;
}
#header
{
    background: #CCCCCC;
}
#default
{
    display: block;
    height: 100px;
    background: #64D989;
}
#sticky
{
    display: none;
    height: 50px;
    background: #D9D164;
}
#footer
{
    background: #EEEEEE;
}
```

[fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/m6LkK/5/)

Answer (score 2):

Because you're setting the #header position to fixed which does exactly that.

Answer (score 1):

`position:fixed` takes the element out of the standard flow of the site, which puts it directly on top of the body content. You can fix that by adding some padding to body. See here: http://jsfiddle.net/wxRtX/

Comment: doesn't look ugly at the start?

Comment: Well, yeah... I suppose `position:fixed` should be added to the #header from the start instead of relying on jQuery to do it.

Answer (score 0):

you can add below css and make it work

```
#page
{
    padding-top: 100px;
}
```